# Posting as public to FB using SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there anyway to force or even make by default when I post on behalf of the user to make the posts public  ?? I am posting using FB sdk for JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is of course no way of *forcing* that.

All you can do is set a default *suggestion* in your app’s settings (Auth Dialog settings).

When using dialogs to post, the user can change that suggestion right there.

And if your app is posting in the background, without direct user interaction, the user can still overwrite your suggestion on their applications settings tab in their user profile.